# Why does my Web ASP controller in ASP.NET 4.5 respond with an error for several controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net, mongodb, asp.net-web-api, .net-4.5

I have a Web API, it's using ASP.NET 4.5. I have tested that API returns a success response, and then after several months, my controller suddenly returns error responses.

This is how I inject my repository:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Which part is throwing error and what is the error message?

Comment: the error cant parse object formbody and several controller cant parse return object, i ussualy access the web api using http client

Comment: Any changes made in the api or at the client application? Are able to get the exact payload which is not parsing? How it is different from the expected payload?

Comment: nothing any changes,it occur after several month, then i fix it by republish, and then it appear error again after a month or 3 days

Answer (score 0):

this error occurs mostly when you haven't properly implemented DI. One of your controller is causing an issue, that's why in error response it shows you all controllers name.

Try this below code in your startup class

```cs
builder.RegisterApiControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()).InstancePerRequest();
```

Comment: what does code above cause injecttion transient ? instanceperRequest, may my repository create instance per request, it harmfull to database